# Color of border in polygon mapshow MatLab

Tags: matlab, colors, maps, polygon, matlab-figure

How can I change the color of the borders of polygons in a choropleth map in MatLab? (While keeping at the same time the colors inside the polygons). Reproducible code below.

```
      MapLatLimit = [41 48];
MapLonLimit = [-74 -66];

NEstates = shaperead('usastatelo', 'UseGeoCoords', true, 'BoundingBox', [MapLonLimit' MapLatLimit']);
datawithNaN = [30 20 30 NaN 40 50 NaN NaN];
% Here replace NaNs with a number (treat as category):
datawithNaN(isnan(datawithNaN)) = 0;
datawithNaN = num2cell(datawithNaN);

% Here I create a color map, using white for NaN (category = 0);
mycolormap = [  1 1 1;...
               .4 .1 .9;...
               .3 .2 .8;...
               .2 .3 .7;...
               .1 .4 .6];
[NEstates.datawithNaN] =  deal(datawithNaN{:});
densityColors = makesymbolspec('Polygon', {'datawithNaN',   [0 50], 'FaceColor', mycolormap});
mapshow(NEstates, 'DisplayType', 'polygon',  'SymbolSpec', densityColors)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the property `'EdgeColor'` you can change the colour to any colour. In the example below I selected the colour red, `r`. For more colour options: [MATLAB Documentation: ColorSpec (Color Specification)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorspec.html). The colour can also be defined as an RGB triplet matrix in the form of an array `[r g b]`:

Where,

`r` → Red intensity ranging from 0 to 1. 
`g` → Green intensity ranging from 0 to 1. 
`b` → Blue intensity ranging from 0 to 1.

```
densityColors = makesymbolspec('Polygon', {'datawithNaN',   [0 50], 'FaceColor', mycolormap,'EdgeColor','r'});
```

[image: Colouring Map Borders]

Comment: Thanks a lot @MichaelTr7, I imagined it was something simple but I was not being able to find where/how to add the change in the property. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, happy to help.